# Get values from a parent field - Odoo10

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-10

I have 2 fields F1 and F2 in a form. Field F1 is a popup. On popping up it has 2 more fields F3 and F4. I need to access value stored in F3 and store it in F2.

Attached image might help to understand the workflow.
[Click to view this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0zMxU.jpg)

Here are some more details to my question

Here is what I tried.

```
class JobJob(models.Model):
    _name='job.job'
    address = field.Char('Address')


Class Dailylog(models.Model):
    job_id = fields.Many2one('job.job', 'Job')
    def check(self):
        address = fileds.Char(related='job_id.address')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I got it right your question, you want to use relation field.
In my code, you use your relation with the `MyModel` to get `f3` and `f4`, so you don't have to store it. (Of course, you can, if you take `store=True` in the relation filed definition, when you don't store it, you can't search in that fields.)

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    _name = 'my.model'

    f3 = fields.Char(string='F3')
    f4 = fields.Char(string='F4')

class MyOtherModel(models.Model):
    _name = 'my.other.model'

    f1 = fields.Many2one('my.model', 'F1')
    f2 = fields.Char('F2')
    f3 = fields.Char(related='f1.f3')
    f4 = fields.Char(related='f1.f4')
```

Now you have both field (`f3` and `f4`), so easy to show them on your form.

**EDIT** (*Question changed*)

***TL;DR***: You can't define field in a method.

I know this is just a logical field, but your code is a generic change on relation model. If you could do that, that means you can change database schema  on the fly. So sometimes one times address field exits, sometime not...but when it it isn't exist, it will wipe earlier loaded data in to this field. This may a huge inconsistency risk.

Comment: Hey! Thank you for the input. Its clear now, this should work. 
But when I tried I got "RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded".   I have edited my question with what I tried, can you please look into it. Both the classes are in different py files.

Comment: @user3571631 hahoooo, have you any comment to my solution? I am really excited, is it work fine?

Comment: Very good. You should accept my answer (just click on the pipe on the right next to answer). Have a nice day and enjoy yourself! :)